# Execute ajax function until get success of another ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to execute an ajax function, the detail here is that i want to execute this function until another ajax function return success.

This is the function that will i have to wait to return success (`try..catch` block)

**Ajaxfunction1**

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url :url,
        data : parameters,
        success : function(msg) {
            try {
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(msg);
                console.debug(msg);
                //SendToDMS(msg);
            } catch (e) {
                $("#SaveConfig").removeAttr("disabled");
                toastr.error(msg + '.', "Message");
            }
        },
        failure : function(msg) {
            $("#SaveConfig").removeAttr("disabled");
            toastr.error('Error: ' + msg + '.', "Message");
        }
    });
```

I want something like this:

```
while ( Ajaxfunction1 != success ) { // while the previous ajax function not return success execute this another ajax function
    $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url :url,
            data : parameters,
            success : function(msg) {
                // something on success
            },
            failure : function(msg) {
                // something when comes an error
            }
        });
}
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks for your help

Comment: Make it a function and call the function from the success of the first ajax call, use deferred objects with $.when, use a setTimeout function to check for a flag that is set within the success of the first function. Any of those 3 are viable, some are 'cleaner' than others.

Comment: What do you mean "while the ajax function returns success", you're only executing it once, it either fails or succeeds ?

Comment: i need to execute the second ajax call several times till the first one get the success event, that's why i put the while block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the returned Deferred from `$.ajax` and check it's [**`state()`**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/) to see if it's resolved, rejected or pending, so something like this with a recursive function should do what you want.

```
var waitFor = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : url,
    data : parameters
}).done(function(msg) {
    try {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(msg);
    } catch (e) {
        $("#SaveConfig").removeAttr("disabled");
        toastr.error(msg + '.', "Message");
    }
}).fail(function(msg) {
    $("#SaveConfig").removeAttr("disabled");
    toastr.error('Error: ' + msg + '.', "Message");
});

(function rec() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url  : url,
        data : parameters
    }).always(function() {

        if (waitFor.state() != 'resolved') rec();

    }).done(function(msg) {
        // something on success
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        // something when comes an error
    });
})();
```